# Group by two columns with OR logic ignoring nulls (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

II have the table that holds two ID values. The key is combination of that ID, one of ID may be null but not both. The keys are compared ignoring null values. Something like that:

```
ID1  ID2   TIMESTAMP
___________________________
A    1     2023-09-01 11:00
A    null  2023-09-01 10:00
B    null  2023-09-01 09:00
null 1     2023-09-01 08:00 
B    2     2023-09-01 07:00
```

According to data model ID1 shoult match to at most one ID2 (so case A 1, B 1 is not possible). I need to count rows by the *keys*, i.e. rows 1,2,4 and rows 3,5 should be counted as the same and group by should produce the result something like that:

```
ID1 ID2 COUNT
_____________
A    1    3
B    2    2
```

Is it possible to do that with SQL? I am on Oracle 19c.

Comment: There is no way to answer this unless there exist one or more columns which provides the exact _ordering_ you seem to think is here.

Comment: @JonasMetzler, in fact there is a logic that ID1 must match either to unique ID2 or null. Combination "A 2" may exist because of errors, but I even don't know how to calculate "A null" in this case so don't want to add that complexity ...

Comment: I still think this is 1) bad DB design and 2) very few sample data. Hard to say what exact logic is needed. Maybe something like this? https://dbfiddle.uk/qeWjDkkL

Comment: @JonasMetzler, thank you for your suggestions, there are good ideas I can use. Please accept my apologies for not very well prepared question.

Comment: I don't understand the rules. "first three and second two rows should be counted as the same"? Then null|1 and B|2 are in the same group? Why? They have nothing in common. What exactly is the rule that shall apply here?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, I've updated the question, sorry for confusion.

Comment: Okay, what about ties? If you have A|1, B|1 and null|1, should the null|1 count for A|1, for B|1, for both or for none?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, as I told above in my comment this case is not possible in my data model. ID1 should match to at most one ID2. I understand that model is not consistent but this is what I need to work with ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated sub-query:

```sql
SELECT id1,
       id2,
       ( SELECT COUNT(*)
         FROM   table_name c
         WHERE  ( c.id1 = t.id1 AND c.id2 = t.id2 )
         OR     ( c.id1 = t.id1 AND c.id2 IS NULL )
         OR     ( c.id1 IS NULL AND c.id2 = t.id2 )
       ) AS cnt
FROM   table_name t
WHERE  id1 IS NOT NULL
AND    id2 IS NOT NULL;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID1, ID2, TIMESTAMP) AS
SELECT 'A',  1,     DATE '2023-09-01' + INTERVAL '11:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A',  null,  DATE '2023-09-01' + INTERVAL '10:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',  null,  DATE '2023-09-01' + INTERVAL '09:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT null, 1,     DATE '2023-09-01' + INTERVAL '08:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',  2,     DATE '2023-09-01' + INTERVAL '07:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID1 | ID2 | CNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3 |
| B | 2 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/U05kPC1S)

Comment: Without grouping the query will return duplicate data if I have more than one records with the same key, for example two A 1, etc.

Comment: @Vadim Lotarev: You never mentioned duplicate data in your table. Well, just add `DISTINCT` to the query and thus remove duplicate results.

Comment: @MT0: No need for `DATE '2023-09-01' + INTERVAL '11:00' HOUR TO MINUTE`. For timestamps use the `TIMESTAMP` literal: `TIMESTAMP '2023-09-01 11:00:00'`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner When using `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT`, there is a difference. My version creates a `DATE` column, yours creates a `TIMESTAMP` column and the OP's data did not have fractional seconds so, although I did consider using `TIMESTAMP` literals, I decided to use `DATE`s.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for groups where both ID1 and ID2 are not null. In these groups you want to count all rows that match either ID. Use a correlated subquery for this.

```
select
  id1, id2,
  (
    select count(*)
    from mytable all_matches
    where all_matches.id1 = mytable.id1
       or all_matches.id2 = mytable.id2
  ) as total
from mytable
where id1 is not null and id2 is not null;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/UQcmFgGC

Comment: Oops I didn't see MT0's second answer. So, mine is just a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I ended up with the following query:

```sql
with subquery as (
    select * from (
    select COALESCE(id1, LAG(id1) OVER (PARTITION BY id2 order by id1)) as id1, 
           COALESCE(id2, LAG(id2) OVER (PARTITION BY id1 order by id2)) as id2,
    count(*) count 
    from T group by id1, id2 order by id1, id2
    )
)
select id1, id2, sum(count) from subquery group by id1, id2 order by id1, id2
```

Thank to [JonasMetzler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18794826/jonas-metzler)  for ideas.

Comment: This is counting rows 1, 2 and 4 for the `A, 1` tuple and rows 3 and 5 for the `B, 2` tuple [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1qxErDbe) but your question states that you want to count rows 1, 2, and 3 for `A, 1` and 4 and 5 for `B, 2`. Although it may get the expected answer, I think this is only coincidence as it ignores the `TIMESTAMP` column.

Comment: @MTO, I've updated the question, sorry for confusion.

Comment: This query is overly complicated. See my answer on how easy it actually is. :-) Oops, now I see that MT0 has already posted almost the same answer...

Answer (score 0):

Note: this answers the [5th revision of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77021214/5) and not the later edits.

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` for row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  ORDER BY timestamp
  MEASURES
    id1_id2.id1 AS id1,
    id1_id2.id2 AS id2,
    COUNT(*) AS cnt
  PATTERN ( (null_id1* id1_id2 null_id1*) | (null_id2* id1_id2 null_id2*) )
  DEFINE
    id1_id2  AS id1 IS NOT NULL AND id2 IS NOT NULL,
    null_id1 AS id1 IS NULL,
    null_id2 AS id2 IS NULL
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID1, ID2, TIMESTAMP) AS
SELECT 'A',  1,     DATE '2023-09-01' + INTERVAL '11:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A',  null,  DATE '2023-09-01' + INTERVAL '10:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',  null,  DATE '2023-09-01' + INTERVAL '09:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT null, 1,     DATE '2023-09-01' + INTERVAL '08:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B',  2,     DATE '2023-09-01' + INTERVAL '07:00' HOUR TO MINUTE FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID1 | ID2 | CNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 2 | 2 |
| A | 1 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wKsbyMKg)

Comment: Invert the 2 'A' rows and it doesn't work anymore, the count of 'A' will be 2 instead of 3, if you have a ('A',n != 1) row the ('A',null) will be counted twice, ...
looks like the data and rules specification is too "fragile" to get a reliable answer.

Comment: @p3consulting Swapping the time on the `A` rows (to swap  their order) works and gives a count of 3 [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AKfnaBam). If you get a different answer then you need to provide a [MRE] which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/k-mliCdC